# Is it possible to recover when a slot has been removed during a Flink streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a standalone cluster where there is a Flink streaming job with 1-hour event time windows. After 2-3 hour of a run, the job dies with the "org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The assigned slot ... was removed" exception.

The job is working well when my windows are only 15minutes.

How can the job recover after losing a slot? 
Is it possible to run the same calculations on multiple slots to prevent this error? 
Shall I increase any of the timeouts? if so which one?

Comment: Any errors in the task or job manager ?

Comment: This error is most certainly the result of some additional error than the cause itself. Could You paste logs or chceck whether any more errors are logged ? Probably You should look into the logs of taskmanager.

Answer (score 0):

Flink streaming job recovers from failures from [checkpoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/checkpoints.html). If your checkpoint is externalized, for example in S3. You can manually or ask Flink automatically recover from the most recent checkpoint.

Depends on your upstream message queuing service, you will likely get duplicated messages. So it's good to make your ingestion idempotent.

Also, the slot removed failure can be the symptom of various failures.

- underlying hardware
- network
- memory pressure

What do you see in the task manager log that was removed?